# Wait for an SSRS report to finish loading

Tags: c#, reporting-services, watin

I am using WatiN to open an SSRS report. Initially, when the report is opened, it show the message "Report is being generated".
I want to wait till the report gets generated.

I used WaitForComplete but it never returns.

1. If the report gets generated, the program should continue.
2. Else show the error that the report failed to generate.

**Edit No 1**

```
//create IE window
WatiN.Core.IE window = new WatiN.Core.IE();
window.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.ShowMaximized);

//go to the URL
window.GoTo("http://10.205.10.173");

//fill details for login
window.TextField(Find.ByName("User")).TypeText("bcadmin");
window.TextField(Find.ByName("Password")).TypeText("Test123!");
window.SelectList(Find.ByName("Application")).SelectByValue("appBCCIFrys");
window.Button(Find.ByName("dbbSystemLogin")).Click();

//go to Activity Re-cap Report
window.Span(Find.ByText("Reports")).Click();
window.Span(Find.ByText("Activity Re-cap Report")).Click();

//fill details for it
window.SelectList(Find.ByName("DbbDataCtrl_PnlARecapReportingdeARecapReportingRecordType_")).SelectByValue("00");
window.SelectList(Find.ByName("DbbDataCtrl_PnlARecapReportingdeARecapReportingSection_")).SelectByValue("00");

//press next
window.Image(Find.ByAlt("Next")).Click();

//change checkbox to option 2
window.RadioButton(Find.ByValue("1")).Checked = true;

//fill date
window.TextField(Find.ByName("DbbDataCtrl_PnlARecapReporting8NextdeARecapReportingIndividualDate_")).TypeText("12/12/2012");

//press create report
window.Image(Find.ByAlt("Create Report")).Click();

//Thread.Sleep(60000);

//connect to the new page opened
IE report = IE.AttachToNoWait<IE>(Find.ByTitle("New Activity Recap"), 200);

**//HERE I WANT TO WAIT TILL THE REPORT IS LOADED AND FETCH VALUES
//IF IT DOES NOT LOAD (or throws any error) WITHIN 2 MINS, MOVE FOWWARD**

//logout
window.Span(Find.ByText("Logout")).Click();
window.Close();
report.Close();
```

Comment: Can you post your current logic that checks for the SSRS report?

Answer (score 0):

Praise the LORD! This one took me a few days to figure out!

I was trying to access the "inner html" to wait until "Report Generated..." existed. However, I was not able to do this with my limited knowledge of Watin. But lets move on to the solution!

It finally hit me to see if I can capture when the "Report is Generating..." was removed from the screen. However, since it is never removed from the html I instead went with this nifty little check.

```
while (reportViewer.Span("athenaReportViewer_ReportsViewer_ctl03").Style.Display.ToString() != "none")
{
   Console.WriteLine("This enabled...");
}
Console.WriteLine("DISABLED!!!");
```

So we instead check the style property "Display" to have the value "none". XD